# Synonymize [basic-authentication] and [http-basic-authentication]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[basic-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic-authentication) and [http-basic-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-basic-authentication) are the same thing (even having the same excerpt).  We don't need both.